# Xcode Version 9.3 beta stalling out when running simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode9-beta

I'm finding that very frequently (many times per hour) Xcode will just stall out at the "Waiting for iPhone X to start" step.  The only solution to this is to force quit the Xcode process and try again.  Has any one encountered this and know of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered it and my solution is to file a bug report with Apple. Go ye and do likewise. I'm not being snarky! It is desperately important to bombard Apple with reports of this, so that they understand that it is real and widespread.